# How to adjust zoom level to fit boundary and then center map in marker offset?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a google map (com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap) where I have some markers set.

I am able to, separately,

1) adjust zoom level and center the map on a boundary:

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(getZoomBounds(), 10));
```

and

2) center the map above one of the markers:

```
LatLng poiSelectedLatLng = new LatLng(markerSelected.getPosition().latitude 
    + offset, markerSelected.getPosition().longitude);

mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(poiSelectedLatLng));
```

but, for the life of me, I can't just do both, adjust the zoom level using newLatLngBounds and then center the map somewhere else. Whatever I do last is what I see happening in the map.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using both `moveCamera` and `animateCamera`...

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(getZoomBounds(), 10));
LatLng poiSelectedLatLng = new LatLng(markerSelected.getPosition().latitude 
    + offset, markerSelected.getPosition().longitude);

mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(poiSelectedLatLng));
```

`moveCamera` will move directly to that spot while `animateCamera` will provide the moving effect. They are linear in nature so one will happen after the other however layering them as I have done above will provide the potential *effect* you are looking for.

If you are trying to see the actual movement of both calls on the UI you will need to register for the callback post the completion of the animation as needed.

Comment: There is no need for event bus, thread or anything else to chain two animateCamera calls. There is a callback for when animation finishes.

Answer (score 6):

For future visitors this is how you can chain camera animations:

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(getZoomBounds(), 10), 2000, new CancelableCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        LatLng poiSelectedLatLng = new LatLng(markerSelected.getPosition().latitude + offset, markerSelected.getPosition().longitude);
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(poiSelectedLatLng));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
    }
});
```

Also see [AnimateCameraChainingExampleActivity.java](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-v2-demo/blob/master/NewMapsDemo/src/pl/mg6/newmaps/demo/AnimateCameraChainingExampleActivity.java) for an example how to chain infinitely.

Comment: There is so little useful information on the internet and this is part of it.